# Jquery drag and drop across two divs

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I have two div's that are sortable within the div's and i also want to drag n drop them across the two divs.Can anyone tell me how can i do that.
For example i have two list of members in two divs i want them to be draggable n droppable in across the divs.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean but if you are using the `jQuery.sortable` to make each div content sortable, you can use the property `connectWith` to specify the other sortable list you want to be able to drag items to. Refer to: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable#option-connectWith.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set both divs draggable and droppable?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the container divs droppable and the list element divs draggable:.